Groovy TypeChecking from Java Source
I am trying to upgrade a Java code base which parses groovy code that users give to be compatible with the Groovy parrot parser, and I am struggling.
Before parrot, we would catch syntax errors like this:
@Test(expected = MultipleCompilationErrorsException.class)
    public void testFailingOldWay() {
        CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
        config.setPluginFactory(ParserPluginFactory.antlr2());
        new GroovyShell(config).parse("this is not valid");
    }

with antlr4 / parrot, that code actually doesn't throw any parsing errors. At first I thought this was a bug, but I understand now, that it is possible to pass in dynamic methods and variables that it could somehow be valid
@Test
public void testFailingNewWayDoesNotWork() {
    CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
    // Expect the next line to throw a compilation error, but it doesn't.
    new GroovyShell(config).parse("this is not valid");
}

I have a list of variables that are to be available to the scripts provided, so I thought I would do something like:
@Test(expected = MultipleCompilationErrorsException.class)
public void testNewIdea() {
    CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
    config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(TypeChecked.class));
    new GroovyShell(config).parse("this is not valid");
}

This works, but I can't find a way to tell it to allow certain variables to be undefined.
I read the docs, and looked at this stack overflow post:
Embedded Groovy: How to use static type checking with external variables?
but the docs only seem to get me half way for the java part, and the post is all about doing it in groovy, which I am not.
In Java, the extensions parameter doesn't seem to exist.
I think that I need to make a custom annotation and a custom type checking extension, but I am not sure exactly.
My plan was this:
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformationClass;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass("flexagon.fd.model.script.AllowUnresolvedVariables")
public @interface NoUnresolvedVariablesAnnotation
{
}

and
public class AllowUnresolvedVariables
  extends AbstractTypeCheckingExtension
{

  public AllowUnresolvedVariables(final StaticTypeCheckingVisitor typeCheckingVisitor)
  {
    super(typeCheckingVisitor);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleUnresolvedVariableExpression(final VariableExpression vexp)
  {
    return true;
  }

}

But, I get a nullpointer trying to reference them in my config setup.
I made a simple project on github to show the issues I am having:
https://github.com/karlhenselin/testGroovy
I appreciate any help you can provide.

the simplest way to set base class for your script:
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ASTTransformationCustomizer;
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked;
import groovy.lang.*;

//you can build base class dynamically or declare it statically
String props = "";
props += "\n public abstract class MyBaseScript1 extends groovy.lang.Script {";
props += "\n   String x";
props += "\n   int y";
props += "\n }";

GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class base = gcl.parseClass(props);

CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(TypeChecked.class));
config.setScriptBaseClass(base.getName());

//set classloader to help GroovyShell to find "MyBaseScript1" class
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(gcl, config);

Script script = gs.parse("assert x instanceof String; def z = y/123; println z;");


I like the idea, as it looks simple, but it isn't working for me. I can push it, but I get an error about the classloaders. General error during instruction selection: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class Script1 cannot access its abstract superclass example.TestGroovy$MyScript (Script1 is in unnamed module of loader groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader @23aae55; example.TestGroovy$MyScript is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
I would like to be able to add in the variable names at runtime in Java if possible also, although I think I could do it at compile time if needed.

about class loading - just declare your class in a separate file to have nice class name like "example.MyScript"

I tried that too, and got a similar error. Also, I think the value would end up being used at eval time wouldn't in instead of the one I bound?

i added kind of dynamic. note usage of gcl classloader parameter for GroovyShell: new GroovyShell(gcl, config);

Wowsers, that is a truly amazing solution to my problem. I don't think I would have ever come up with it. Thanks for the effort and time you spent on this to refine it and help me out! Thanks so much.
